# php web service not accepting POST values

Tags: php, json, web-services

I have made web service in php, which sends email to seller with information which is sent in parameters. If we are sending those information in GET, the web service works well.
But if we send that information in POST, the web service (php script) shows nothing.

Here is url of that web service :

http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/carsGuide/contactSeller.php?seller_id=0&name=Anjum&email=abc@ccc.com&mobile=00923344239490&area=Dubai&message=This%20is%20test%20message.

Currently i am just showing param passed using

print_r($_REQUEST);

Well this is working fine because i am sending those paramerters in GET but I am trying to send those parameters in POST using chrome extension "Simple REST client", I am getting nothing.

I guess, I need to set headers in my script, but not sure about that. Or when calling that web service we need to set any thing header in request.

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Thanks..
Anjum

Here is how request is send :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: this.getBaseUrl() + webServiceUrl,
                timeout: 240000,
                method: httpMethod,
                disableCaching: false,
                useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
                jsonData : {
             "seller_id":seller_id,
             "name":name,
             "email":email,
             "mobile":mobile,
             "area":area,
             "message":message              },
                scope: me,
                success: function(response) {
                 Ext.Viewport.unmask();
                    successCallBack(response);
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                 Ext.Viewport.unmask();
                   failureCallback(response);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Perhaps PHP is configured to not include POST in `$_REQUEST`.  What do you see in `$_POST`?

Comment: I am getting "Array ( )" doing like print_r($_POST);

Comment: double check that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is set to `POST`. That will tell you if the client is actually posting vs get. Also, does the client request show up in the network tab of developer tools? If so, you should be able to see everything in the request. Make sure it looks fine.

Comment: I am updating it in my actual post how the request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are actually setting the post fields data in the REST client, and not HTTP headers, they are different things.

Here was my test to prove it works:

```
curl http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/carsGuide/contactSeller.php -d 'test=1'
Array
(
    [test] => 1
)
```

Comment: Well i am still don't get how i can set it through REST client. Any ways, the call will be made from Ajax (Sencha) through Ajax query. Can you please tell me how that call be made so my web service get values in POST.

Comment: I am updating it in my actual post how the request is sent.